# How to embed the PostCSS's CSS parser into web pages?

Tags: javascript, postcss

I recently saw a demo page of a CSS polyfill which uses PostCSS's CSS parser to read and parse style sheets.

That [demo page is here](https://philipwalton.github.io/talks/2016-12-02/demos/4/). It's the step 4 of a [step-by-step tutorial](https://philipwalton.com/articles/the-dark-side-of-polyfilling-css/). If you check the console, you can see that it logs an object containing all parsed CSS rules for showing the power of the CSS parser.

I'm trying to create a CSS polyfill. And I would like to use PostCSS's CSS parser to read and parse style sheets, too. Its CSS parser probably is the most up-to-date one and can correctly parse [@supports at-rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports).

But after reading the [usage of PostCSS on GitHub](https://github.com/postcss/postcss#usage), I still could not find a way to embed PostCSS's CSS parser into my web page like how we usually embed jQuery.

The npm command mentioned in the usage (such as the following line) is for development environment and isn't what I'm looking for.

```
postcss --use autoprefixer -c options.json -o main.css css/*.css
```

I'm confused and not even sure whether the parser is available publicly or not. Can someone please shed some light on this?

Comment: postcss is a development tool which parse postcss to css. you could use as dev dependency and use with gulp,webpack build system and not sure what your are trying to do.

Comment: @Boobalan I'm trying to embed PostCSS's CSS parser in my web page like how we embed jQuery. If you check the source code of the [demo page of the polyfill](https://philipwalton.github.io/talks/2016-12-02/demos/4/), you can see this line of code: `<script src="index.bundle.js"></script>`. That file contains the CSS parser. The problem is that I couldn't find the original JavaScript code of the CSS parser to embed.

Comment: Please have a quick on my answer .. you could use browserify  to build your js with postcss

Comment: @Boobalan I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any way you could try this. Make use of browserify and postcss-browserify plugin.

links:

http://browserify.org/.

https://github.com/zoubin/browserify-postcss

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand it. So the CSS parser is officially only available in development environment and isn't available in client-side like jQuery is. Anyway, I will try it.

Comment: yes, browser doesn't support require('postcss'). so with the help of browserify  we include postcss lib in our bundle

Comment: Thanks for confirming that :)